# SQL Server 2012 Failed to launch local ScenarioEngine.exe

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have been trying install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition for quite some time now..
I always get "stuck" at Install Setup Files, the install wizard just hides,

Now, i reviewed the log file for setup, which is: SqlSetup_1

There,i found these errors

**Attempting to launch process (null)SQLServer2012\x86\ScenarioEngine.exe
Error: Failed to launch process
Error: Failed to launch local ScenarioEngine.exe: 0x80070003**

The full SqlSetup_1 log:

http://pastebin.com/Ehvi1Nvm

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*(Community Wiki answer from comments provided by [Jon Seigel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59568/sql-server-2012-failed-to-launch-local-scenarioengine-exe/171321#comment107505_59568).)*</sub>

Try putting the install files in a location that is not on your desktop. It seems there's an issue resolving the base path to that executable